What is the definition of \partial (∂) by using \DeclareMathSymbol
I want to know the definition of "\partial (∂)" by using \DeclareMathSymbol. For example, the definition of "\alpha (α)" by using \DeclareMathSymbol is
\DeclareMathSymbol\alpha{\mathord}{letters}{"0B}.

And I also want to know which font files contain the symbol "\partial (∂)"

Welcome! You can find the definition in fontmath.ltx: \DeclareMathSymbol{\partial}{\mathord}{letters}{"40}. This is unless you've loaded a class or package which changes it, of course. Which font files are you interested in? The answer depends on your class, relevant packages and chosen engine. Even then 'font files contain' is potentially ambiguous as the picture of the symbol may be in one place and its metrics in another, but also the route to these may not be direct ....

Based on your comment, I find this symbol in cmmi10.pfb. Thank you! @cfr

You can find the default definition in fontmath.ltx, part of the base distribution:
 \DeclareMathSymbol{\partial}{\mathord}{letters}{"40}

This tells us that the symbol, by default, will be taken from the alphabet defined for letters. Earlier in the same file, we find
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}

and
\SetSymbolFont{letters}  {bold}{OML}{cmm} {b}{it}

So the normal and bold symbols will, by default, use font encoding OML, font family cmm, font series b and font shape it.
If you have a default set up i.e. your class doesn't change the default, you aren't loading packages which change it and you are using a non-unicode engine (TeX or pdfTeX), these fonts are defined in omlcmm.fd.
This file says:
\ProvidesFile{omlcmm.fd}
        [2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions]
\DeclareFontFamily{OML}{cmm}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}%
     {<5><6><7><8><9>gen*cmmi%
      <10><10.95>cmmi10%
      <12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>cmmi12%
      }{}

So cmmi at the appropriate optical size.
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}{%
      <5><6><7><8><9>gen*cmmib%
      <10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>cmmib10%
      }{}

Likewise, cmmib.
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{cmm}{bx}{it}%
   {<->ssub*cmm/b/it}{}
\endinput

We then look in the appropriate .map file e.g. pdftex.map for pdfTeX:
cmmi10 CMMI10 <cmmi10.pfb
cmmi12 CMMI12 <cmmi12.pfb
cmmi5 CMMI5 <cmmi5.pfb
cmmi6 CMMI6 <cmmi6.pfb
cmmi7 CMMI7 <cmmi7.pfb
cmmi8 CMMI8 <cmmi8.pfb
cmmi9 CMMI9 <cmmi9.pfb
cmmib10 CMMIB10 <cmmib10.pfb

So the fonts used will be the relevant sizes of the postscript type1 fonts (*.pfb). At least, these files contain the pictures of the characters (glyphs). The metric are contained in .tfm files with corresponding names e.g. for cmmi10.pfb, the metrics are in cmmi10.tfm. .tfms are binary. You can read them using e.g. tftopl or you can fine the not-particularly-TeX metrics in cmmi10.afm.
But if you are using e.g. luaTeX or you are loading a class which changes the fonts or you are using packages which do so, any or all of this might be changed.
